# Highlight listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've create a navigation drawer, but instead of putting a listview, I placed a relativelayout with two listviews inside

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/nd_background"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/nd_image_text"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/navigation_drawer_image"/>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nd_list_1"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:divider="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_below="@id/nd_list_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/darker_gray"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nd_list_2"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider"
            android:divider="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now I want to highlight a listview item when a specific row was selected, so I use the listview function **setSelection**, but the selected row does not get highlighted. I did work when I put only a listview into my navigation drawer, but not for this.